# Power BI DAX count occurences

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following data set:

```
KEY                    CNT
A-S000218691600_14       1
A-S000218691600_14       2
A-S000218691600_14       3
A-S000218696400_1        1
A-S000218691600_14       4
A-S000218691600_14       5
A-S000218691600_14       6
A-S000218691600_14       7
A-S000218691600_14       8
A-S000218693200_1        1
A-S000218691600_14       9
A-S000218691600_14      10
A-S000218691600_14      11
A-S00021869245175.29_1   1
A-S000218691600_14      12
A-S000218691600_14      13
A-S00021869110339.26_1   1
A-S000218691600_14      14
A-S000218696400_1        2
A-S000218691600_7        1
A-S000218691600_7        2
A-S000218691600_7        3
A-S000218691600_7        4
A-S000218691600_7        5
A-S000218691600_7        6
A-S000218691600_7        7
A-S0002186917600_1       1
```

In Excel I can create the CNT column by using `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)` but I cannot have the same result in DAX.
I have tried the following but without generating the same output:

```
 cnt = calculate(
     COUNTROWS(table),
     filter(
        ALLEXCEPT(table, table[key]),
        table[key]=EARLIER(table[key])
    )
 )
```

Could someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: The value of your `cnt` column appears to depend on the position in the column (index) of each value, which depends on the sort order of your table. Do you have another column on which you are sorting / indexing?

Comment: No, it does not look at the position, just try the formula in Excel, it will do the job

Comment: The Excel formula is also using the relative row reference to determine the position in the list... You NEED another column to achieve what you want.

Comment: Can't Power BI use the relative position within the data set?

Comment: Only if you create an Index. There's no native "row number".

Comment: so, if we generate one index column, how do we create that formula in Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional column to identify the position of each key, in the column.

Add an Index column in the query editor:

```
//Table1
let
    Source = MyTable,
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 1, 1)
in
    #"Added Index"
```

Now you can create the following calculated column:

```
cnt = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        COUNTROWS ( Table1 ),
        FILTER ( 
            ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Key] ),
            Table1[Index] <= EARLIER ( Table1[Index] )
        )
    )
```

Worked example PBIX file: https://pwrbi.com/so_58260475/

## EDIT:

To answer your query about poor performance with large datasets: you can achieve what you want in the query editor, rather than in DAX, by partitioning per Key item, indexing, then recombining the partitions:

```
let
    Source = MyTable,
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 1, 1),
    #"Partition Keys" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"Key"}, {{"Data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.Sort(_, {"Index", Order.Ascending}),"cnt",1,1), type table}}),
    #"Combine Partitions" = Table.Combine(#"Partition Keys"[Data])
in
    #"Combine Partitions"
```

This tests pretty quick, with 400k rows.

Comment: How can this formula be improved in such a way that it supports 400k+ rows? For a small data set it will work but for a large one it's still computing